# How can automatically run docker container

Tags: docker

Our project need to run auto but I don't know how to make it automatically with docker . So how can I run automatically docker container when I restart my PC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ensure the docker daemon is started automatically. This very likely has happened already.
- When launching your container (the `docker run ...` command), make use of the [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies---restart) option.

When using podman, every container will have to have a systemd entry and thus may be considered a separate service. See also [podman-generate-systemd](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-generate-systemd.1.html).